# Most sensible way to model a diary app in with next JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am making a CRUD journaling app and using Next 13. I thought it would be sensible to have each date be a slug in a url, leading to a directory structure like:
`/app/journal/[date]/page.tsx`. One issue I've run into is what the landing page would look like. I want it to be a journal entry for today. So what I've done is place this in my `app/page.tsx`:

```js
export default async function Home() {
  // looks for a journal entry for the current user for today, and if there isn't one, creates a new Journal record and connects it to the user's list of journals. 
  const { createdAt } = await fetchJournal();

  redirect(`/journal/${createdAt}`);
}
```

The problem is that this is causing a *lot* of janky rendering. Like, before, I just rendered a `<Journal>` component right inside `app/page.jsx`, but after switching to this redirect method, the page goes through several odd loading loops that I can only surmise is related to the redirection. The page appears to initially load in as expected, then it fully reloads again out of nowhere.

There's definitely a more sensible way to do this, but I'm hung up on what to do with the `/` route. Or perhaps I should just ditch the whole concept of binding journal dates to routes and use a state manager to keep track of the current journal date and page between them